# File not found in EAR packaging

Tags: ejb, classpath, ear

Inside my .ear

```
-META-INF
-lib
-ejb-shared.jar
-ejb.jar
    -com/ejb/... (classes)
    -fileXml.xml (file I'm trying to access)
-web.war
```

Some description:

- "ejbshared" contains some ejbs and JPA entities
- "ejb" contains some ejbs and JPA entities and uses "ejb-shared" project

The problem is that I can't access fileXml.xml. Inside an EJB bean (of ejb.jar) I've done:

```
File f = new File("fileXml.xml");
System.out.println(f.exists()); // returns false!
```

I don't know why, but it seems that fileXml.xml is not in the classpath, althougth it's present in the .ear, or maybe I'm doing things in the wrong way!

Answer (score 2):

Using `new File("fileXml.xml")` will reference a file in the current working directory of the application server JVM, not relative to your specific application.  Try using:

```
URL url = getClass().getResource("/fileXml.xml");
boolean exists = url != null;
System.out.println(exists);
InputStream input = url.openStream();
// ... read and close input stream
```

Comment: How can I get the file path of this file? I use a lib that needs it. Thanks

Comment: The file path of the JAR file?  There is no portable way to do that.  You can try checking the protocol of the url and extracting the inner file URL, then convert that to a URI, then convert that to a File.  Alternatively, you might check if url.openConnection is an instanceof JarURLConnection, and then use conn.getJarFile().getName().  None of that is guaranteed to work, though.